# extract csv data into xml format

Tags: python, bash

I have a csv file with data like

```
abc1,E,WEL,POI,<DeData L1="Websales" </DeData>
```

I want to extract individual columns and save into xml file as

```
<Data>
   <element1>abc1</element1>
   <element2>E</element2>
   <element3>WEL</element3>
   <element4>abc1</element4>
   <DeData L1="Websales" </DeData>
</Data>
```

and each row from `csv` file should be saved as `separate xml` file.

Any pointers would be very helpful.

Comment: So, what is the actual question here? Are you stuck on reading the csv-file, parsing the contents of the file, formatting the output or writing the output to the files?

Comment: I'm missing a `>` in your XML file.

Comment: @HampusLarsson - I am looking for code to Parse the content and save formatted output to xml file.

Comment: @Geeme We're not a code-writing service here. Could you please provide the code you've tried that didn't work so that we have something to build on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
import pandas as pd

with open('a.csv', 'r') as filee:
  count=0
  temp = filee.readlines()
  for val in temp:
    values = val.rstrip().split(',')
    with open(str(count)+'.xml', 'w') as xml_f:
      string = f'''<Data>
  <element1>{ values[0] }</element1>
  <element2>{ values[1] }</element2>
  <element3>{ values[2] }</element3>
  <element4>{ values[3] }</element4>
  { values[4] }
</Data>'''
      print(string)
      xml_f.write(string.lstrip())
    count += 1
```

Considering csv file contains data in this format

```
abc1,E,WEL,POI,<DeData L1="Websales" </DeData>
abc1,E,WEL,POI,<DeData L1="Websales" </DeData>
abc1,E,WEL,POI,<DeData L1="Websales" </DeData>
abc1,E,WEL,POI,<DeData L1="Websales" </DeData>
```